# Accessing Files and Folders in Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm using Google Apps Script and V2 of the Drive API (I don't think V3 is available in scripts yet) to automate file creation inside of a Team Drive. I'd like to add editors with the script with no success.

I can access the Team Drive and child folders using the `FolderIterator` in the standard `DriveApp` methods.

**Attempt 1**

```js
function addUserToTeam(email, folders) {

  // Open the team drive and get all the folders
  var teamFolders = DriveApp.getFolderById('TEAMDRIVEIDSTRING').getFolders();

  var folders = ["folderIdToMatch"]  // This may hold multiple folders

  try {
  // Loop an array of folder IDs
    for(var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {

      // Check the team drive folders for a matching name
      while(teamFolders.hasNext()) {
        var teamFolder = teamFolders.next();
        if(folders[i] == teamFolder.getId()) {
          teamFolder.addEditor(email);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

This failed with `Exception: Cannot use this operation on a Team Drive item`.

**Attempt 2**

I tried the Drive API by substituting `teamFolder.addEditor(email)` a `Permissions` resource:

```js
if(folders[i] == teamFolder.getId()) {
  var resource = {
    "type":"user",
    "role":"writer",
    "value": email
  }
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, teamFolder.getId());
}
```

This fails with a `File not found` error.

I can find the folder (or file) with `DriveApp` methods. Any attempt at the same with the Drive API fails.

I cannot find any documentation saying Team Drive files are inaccessible with the API. Is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: Can you just add a group to the team drive and use GAS to manage the group? Seems like the easiest way to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more research and digging, here's the solution for people with similar use cases.

1. You can access files to an entire Team Drive *or* to files inside the Drive, but not *folders*. This is done on purpose to prevent accidentally giving access to directories of sensitive information to people who shouldn't have access.
2. To give access, `supportsTeamDrives` is an optional argument in the request body that takes a `boolean` value. Set this to `true` and pass in the API call. A successful function is below.
3. The only way to achieve the outcome I described is to use multiple Team Drives and give access to users based on some event. Another option would be to promote a user to Full permissions (from edit or view) for the duration of the project and then revoke when completed.

#### Add a user to a Team Drive

(This also works for single files in a Drive)

```js
// Using Google Apps Script with v2 of the Drive API enabled
function addToTeamDrive() {      
  var resource = {
      'value': emailString,
      'type': 'user',
      'role': 'writer'
    }

    // If you have several Team Drives, loop through and give access
    try {
      var TeamDrive = Drive.Teamdrives.list();
      for(var i = 0; i < TeamDrive.items.length; i++) {
        if(TeamDrive.items[i].name === "Team Drive String") {
          // This ID may also be a single file inside a Team Drive
          var id = TeamDrive.items[i].id;
        }
      }

      // Add user permissions to the matched Drive
      Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, id, {"supportsTeamDrives": true});
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question on this - I would like to use the same but I am confused as to how I will be able to incorporate the FileIds I have on Sheets. How can I loop through that fileIds inside the the "try {}..."

Answer (score 0):

You can access but there's alot you can't do like `removeFile()` or `getUrl()` even when you have full access. You will still get the

```
{error: "Exception: Cannot use this operation on a Team Drive item."}
```

Workaround is to use `setTrashed()` instead of `removeFile()` on files/folders.