# Searching for folders in Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

`DriveApp.searchFolders(params)` can be used to search Team Drives. However it seems to be limited to folders in Team Drives that the current user created. This seems counter-intuitive with Team drives being a mix of files created by multiple users.

Is there a way to not limit the scope to folders created by the user?

Comment: For full Team Drive support you should probably be using the Drive API and not the Drive Service. There are plenty of related questions as well that you should provide some indication of having reviewed, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive

Comment: You are correct. I did not research this quite fully before posting this question. Thanks for throwing me a bone. Since there is a defined structure for the folders I'm working with I was able to solve my problem Iterating through the folders on the Team Drive by normal Drive service functions.