# How do I add new users to a G-Suite shared drive with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've automated creating G-Suite users based on submissions of a Google Form, and I'd like to also add them to the appropriate shared drives based on their role in our organization (indicated on the form). However I have not been able to find the shared drives to add the permissions-- if I use `.getFoldersByName` it does not find the drives, and if I get a folder *within* the shared drive and use `getParent()` it returns `{}`.

I believe this is because the shared drives are not "folder" objects but another type. I found some code from [this site, pasted below](https://ctrlq.org/code/20514-list-team-drives-google-drive-apps-script) which will fetch folder names and IDs, but I'm not clear on how to modify drive permissions using this information since the folder methods do not work.

```
  try {
    var teamDrives = {},
        baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives",
        token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        params = {
          pageSize: 10,
          fields: "nextPageToken,teamDrives(id,name)"
        };
    do {
      var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(function(p) {
        return [encodeURIComponent(p), encodeURIComponent(params[p])].join("=");
      }).join("&amp;");
      var apiUrl = baseUrl + "?" + queryString;
      var response = JSON.parse(
        UrlFetchApp.fetch( apiUrl, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
        }).getContentText());
      response.teamDrives.forEach(function(teamDrive) {
        teamDrives[teamDrive.id] = teamDrive.name;
      })
      params.pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    } while (params.pageToken);
    return teamDrives;
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: My coworker found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive) which has solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Files and Folders in Team Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive)