# Google Drive API - Adding new users to Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using a Google App Script to automate the creation of some Google Accounts inside our of our domain. I have been having a little trouble with some of the API calls and such, however this question is more related to whether or not the Drive API gives me the ability to do something. I have code below that adds editor permissions to the new user for their needed Shared Drives, however I would like to give them 'Content Manager' access to the Shared Drive. From the documentation I have looked at it, it does not seem like this is possible using the Google Drive API however I wanted to ask here to make sure I am not missing something when proceeding with the rest of my automation.

```
switch(ssValues[i][9]){
    case "Accounting":
      AdminDirectory.Members.insert(groupMember, "notourcompany");
      DriveApp.getFolderById("TH1SDR!v3").addEditor(email);
      break;
```

Does not matter if I need to use a different method or another API to achieve this functionality, I just want to know if it is possible to do this using their API's or SDK's through an App Scripts project.

Documentation:

1. Folder Class-https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder
2. Drive API - Drives - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives
3. Drive API - Permissions - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to manage users over a Shared Drive utilizing the Drive API. The important thing is that you would need to give access over the API and make sure the parameter or argument for `supportsAllDrives` is set to `true`.

There is a [sample Java code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-shareddrives#recover_a_shared_drive_that_doesnt_have_an_organizer) over the official documentation that shows how you can add permissions to a Shared Drive that is "orphaned" or you can test it over it in the permission.create documentation:

[image]

You can test it yourself over [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

As you can see in the image, the function is very similar to the code that was created on an old thread utilizing the Drive API V2, however it is using the argument `supportsTeamDrive`. Sample code that could be edited:

Edit:

I have updated the code based on the one suggested from the thread to a more simplify version.

```js
// Using Apps Script with Advance Google Services v2 of the Drive API enable
function insertPermission() {
  const sharedid= 'sharedDriveID' //ID of the Shared Drive
  var resource = {
    // enter email address here
    value: 'emailtest@domain.com', 
    type: 'user',                
    // choose from: "owner" or "fileOrganizer". File Organizer would basically be the contentManager of a SharedDrive. 
    role: 'fileOrganizer'               
  };
  
  var optionalArgs = {
    sendNotificationEmails: false,
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };
  
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, sharedid, optionalArgs);
  
}
```

You can review the thread and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive).

**References**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-shareddrives

Comment: I have tried to running code similar to that and I recieve an error code that states "Permission value field required"  

`var email = "blah@blah.com";
var resource = {
    "role": "organizer",
    "type": "user",
    "emailaddress": email.toString()
}
Drive.Permissions.insert(resource,"blah", {"supportsTeamDrives": true});`

Comment: Wasn't sure how to add a linebreak in the mini-Markdown format

Comment: I manage to create a sample script, using the reference from above, I notice that you can run it with both "supportsTeamDrives" or "supportsAllDrives" over the optional arguments. Also make sure to add the Advance services on AppScript.

Comment: I do have the Drive API enabled within the AppScript project and have given both the "supportsTeamDrives" and "supportsAllDrives" parameters a try. Still receive the error message **GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Permission value field required** I might just go ahead and attempt to make these API calls in powershell rather than inside of the AppScript project. I do not believe AppScripts has the functionality I need, in more ways than one. I appreciate your help however and will leave the question open for the future or others reference.

Comment: If you are a Super Admin it allows you to run it normally, if you are not, and just an external user with Manager permission on the Shared Drive  you would get that error also, even if the code is correct. I just did a test with two workspace accounts from different domains both with Manager permissions, but one being the Super Admin from Workspace were the Shared Drive is located.

Comment: I will give that a try, I currently have "Almost Admin" privileges inside of our workspace according to our old System's Admin so this may be causing me troubles. I am going to obtain Super Admin privileges and will let comment here if this was my issue.

Comment: I was able to obtain Super Admin privileges this morning, however this did not solve any issues with my script.  At first I was thinking this might have been an issue because I was trying to add users to a Shared Drive that I personally was not a member of, nor was I a manager of the Shared Drive.  Upon further testing, does not make a difference if I am the owner of the Drive or if I am not a member/owner of the Drive, I still receive that same error message. "**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Permission value field required**"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ricardo Jose Velasquez Cruz. I'm a super admin in my org and this solution finally allowed it to work for me. I had to tweak the optionalArgs to include useDomainAdminAccess.

```
// Using Apps Script with Advance Google Services v2 of the Drive API enable
function insertPermission() {
  const sharedid= 'sharedDriveID' //ID of the Shared Drive
  var resource = {
    // enter email address here
    value: 'emailtest@domain.com', 
    type: 'user',                
    // choose from: "owner" or "fileOrganizer". File Organizer would basically be the contentManager of a SharedDrive. 
    role: 'fileOrganizer'               
  };
  
  var optionalArgs = {
    useDomainAdminAccess: true,
    sendNotificationEmails: false,
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };
  
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, sharedid, optionalArgs);
  
}
```